# commas before titles/names

Tags: british-english, commas

1.They visited Portmeirion, Cornwall, which is best remembered as the filming location for the cult 1960's television series, **The Prisoner.**

2.It was beautiful in Portmeirion, made famous by the television series The Prisoner.

3.She walked up the stairs to bring tea for her wicked stepmother, Sarah.

Is 1 correct with the comma before 'The Prisoner', the comma usage being similar to that in 3, or should it be removed?

Without the title of the show in the sentence the information *cult 1960's series* doesn't define it (as there could be others) and therefore the comma should be removed?

Comment: In the first sentence it would be strange to think that *The Prisoner* were a nonessential clause. Only if the previous text made it clear that the subject under discussion were that specific series would it be nonessential. If that were the case, the sentence would almost certainly be phrased as *the filming location for **this** 1960's television series.* But since it uses the *definite* article and there's no indication the show was ever named before, it's likely the comma is a mistake.

Comment: Irrelevant to your question, but Portmeirion's in Wales, not Cornwall.

Comment: @JasonBassford But if "The Prisoner" was the *only **cult*** 1960's series, then it would make sense as a non-essential clause.

Comment: @AIQ Sure, except that [it wasn't](http://www.classic-tv.com/shows/decade/1960s). (And those are only US cult shows. Ironically, *The Prisoner* isn't listed there.)

Comment: Those were not "cult" shows, but highly popular ones.

Comment: To me, the comma helps separate "The Prisoner" from being read as ordinary text, and I think it should be included. If it's omitted, I think "The Prisoner" should be in quotes or in italics. The bold text in the first example helps distinguish the title from the rest of the sentence, but that's lacking in example 2.

Comment: a The actress attended the press screening for horror film, Candyman.

b The actress attended the press screening for horror film.     (Should this example include a comma?) It is essential, right ? Just checking.

Comment: @JasonBassford: The Prisoner not being on a list of US cult 1960's TV programs is not surprising, seeing as it was British (though I agree, about it not being the only the only cult TV program).

Comment: @sharur You're right. A British cult show wouldn't be listed there. My previous comment (at least about US cult shows) doesn't make any sense to me either. ;) However, I doubt it would be the only entry on a list of British cult shows.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I would prefer to use a colon or a dash rather than a comma, if I had to use something to separate the two.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence should not have the comma, since it is the same as #2. In both (restricted appositives), if you omitted "The Prisoner", your reader would wonder what series you meant, and in such cases, most style guides omit the comma. In #3, there is no ambiguity (except in polygamy?) about having a single step-mother, so the comma there is typical and sets off additional information (a non-restrictive appositive).